# Unmanaged network interface 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, server, configuration

I have a Dell PowerEdge R210 II running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with a static IP but my problem is that my network interface appears as unmanaged. So far I have no problems with the server I can connect to it via SSH and the server have internet accesss. Here is the .yaml config generated when I installed Ubuntu.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.197/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  version: 2
```

[Cockpit Networking Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxuSD.png)

Comment: Where does it show as "unmanaged"?  We need to see that.  If Netplan is handling the configurations though, then networkmanager, etc. won't be able to manage the network configuration for that interface.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added an image link from my Cockpit Networking tab.

Comment: Cockpit cannot manage the interfaces that are handled by direct network config in Netplan.  Cockpit is like Network Manager in the way it wants to manage the interfaces.  You need to reconfigure your system one interface at a time.  Start by removing eno2 from the netplan configuration and reboot.  Then you can configure eno2 in Cockpit.  You need to make sure you have access to the Cockpit interface from another management interface before we remove/change the eno1 interface.

Answer (score 0):

I also purchased a Dell PowerEdge R820 recently, slapped Ubuntu Server 22.04 + KVM + Cockpit on it, and found myself in the same situation. The Networking tab sees all of my interfaces, but can't manage any of them. Sadly this doesn't seem to be a well documented issue as it took several hours to find a solution to another problem which also fixed this.

The solution was quite simple though: add `renderer: NetworkManager` to your netplan config.

```
network:
    renderer: NetworkManager
```